# variable column number in qtreewidget

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have a qtreewidget with 1 column header but its children have more columns, I tried below code but I want to hide subsidies header too.
    treeView = new QTreeView;
    treeView->setModel(completer->model());
    treeView->header()->hide();
    treeView->expandAll();

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should reimplement `QHeaderView` for your needs, because `QTreeView` uses number of columns for root items.